# Rerunning DoWork on Background Worker Based on Result?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Let's say I have a backgroundWorker1_DoWork that finds a value in a database and returns it in e.Result.  Let's say I also have a backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted that reads the result.

What I want to be able to do is based on e.Result, I can re-run backgroundWorker1_DoWork, and this I am not sure how to do.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you restart your BackgroundWorker after testing e.Result in your backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted event?

Comment: I'm starting it off using backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsnc(); in the Form1() initiation.  If I want to restart it as you posted, what code do I use and do I just put it in my backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: @Soo - use backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); as Darin suggests. I assume this is how you started the background worker in the first place?

Comment: Works great!
Now a quick little question, should I put the first RunWorkerAsync in Form1() or Form1_Load()?

Comment: Soo, either Form1() and Form1_Load() is ok.

Comment: @Lex Li - I beleive so.  If you need to reference a control and you want to use Form1(), be sure to do so after the call to InitialiseComponent().  Before then the form's controls don't exist.

Answer (score 4):

The same way you are doing it the first time - by invoking the [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2.aspx) method:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Make sure the invocation is conditioned or this loop may run forever :-)